# Make mode belong to multiple other models

Tags: laravel

I have the following 3 models:

```
class Guide extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function game()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Game::class);
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function guides(){
        return $this->hasMany(Guide::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}

class Gamee xtends Model
{
    public function guides(){
        return $this->hasMany(Guide::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

The idea is that a user should create a guide for a specific game. The current code that I have works just fine but I have recently started with Laravel and haven't seen any tutorials where it's done this way. Is there any better solution or is this perfectly fine to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) relationships look just fine to me.

If the database is also properly setup, you can do neat things with the relationships. For instance, I am a big fan of the `with()` function:

```
// Retrieve all users along with their guides and its game.
$users = User::with('guides.game')->all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    foreach ($user->guides as $guide) {
        echo $guide->game->name;
    }
}

// Retrieve all guides along with its user and game.
$guides = Guide::with(['user', 'game'])->all();

// Retrieve all games along with its guides.
$game = Game::with('guides')->all();
```